# Is a comma in an array initializer a sequence point?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am not sure if a comma in an array initializer is actually a sequence point. Has the statement below defined behavior? The standard does not discuss side-effects during aggregate initialization specifically (I think), so I assumed implementation behavior myself, but I had to ask

```
char s[7] = {'a', s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], 0};

 int a[3]= { *ptr++,*ptr++,*ptr++}
```

Comment: Whether it is or not, I hope never to see this code in a real-world application.

Comment: but we can see the second one

Comment: The first one does not compile in gcc.

Comment: Yes, initializer lists are guaranteed left to right.

Comment: @owacoder anyone who works for me and writes code like that, doesn't work for me :)

Comment: An initialiser list has to contain _constant expressions_ only in C. Not sure about C++, this is a different language.

Comment: I'm courious if the Answer there applys to C language too. It seems to be a C++ one.

Comment: Unlike in C++, behavior is undefined in C.